# Putting eclipse under version control

Tags: eclipse, svn, version-control

I'd like to put the entire eclipse IDE (indigo) under version control (for us that would be SVN) to allow developers to checkout the entire IDE ready to go with minimum environment configuration. Did anybody try this? Would this cause problems with actually USING SVN in eclipse?
I could check it in and have users export it, but that would make it trickier to keep it updated.

Comment: This seems somewhat pointless, but I can't think of any conceivable reason why it should cause a problem.

Comment: You should not check in any files that describe local, developer-dependent project set-ups.  You'll hopelessly oil can between developers with every checkout.  Only developer-independent settings should be checked in.

Comment: I understand the impulse as I have worked with some less than great developers and just getting them setup with the development stack can be a bear. My approach is to download eclipse and then install all the common plugins we need, then I zip it up and put it on a shared drive. I don't see the need to put it in SVN, but there is nothing stopping you from doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with @BenjaminLinus approach, get an eclipse, add all the plugins, set up our app's environment specific stuff, zip it up and check it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can... but why? It is just easier to have it in a shared drive for install. You don't need to track version of eclipse.

Comment: This isn't to track versions of eclipse, but to keep a properly configured eclipse available.  When we get a new developer or somebody gets a new computer they have to get eclipse, add all the plugins we use, configure the plugins for our applications, etc.  If the could just checkout the IDE with everything properly configured it would make my job easier.